# extendedProperties sample request in REST API sandbox fails

Tags: outlook-restapi

The Microsoft Office365 REST API Sandbox offers sample requests to test supported REST API methods: https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/

However, all of the POST requests seem to fail, both when using

- the sandbox account
- your own account

for example, these request fail:

- open extensions: create a message with an open extension
- extended properties: create a message with an extended property

This holds for both API versions `V2.0` and `beta`.

Why is this or what is going wrong in the Sandbox?

access, refresh and identity tokens are there and nothing is changed in the sample requests...

Comment: @AidaNowzari of your APIs? What do you mean with that?
And no, I don't think I can, because then I would be publicly disclosing my tokens. the sandbox account including password does not work for me, it tells me to reset my password :/

Comment: @Marc Lafleur I should have added to my question the fact that the ExtendedProperties REST API calls don't work. We get 500 server errors. that is why I included the `outlook-add-in`and `officejs` tags...
I'll create a separate issue for this, as this is the last call we need to get working to completely remove EWS SOAP requests from our add-in.

Comment: still no followup