# using ExtendedProperties in the Outlook REST API to set Message item headers

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-restapi

It is possible to **request** message headers in the C# API:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.internetmessageheaders(exchg.80).aspx

Is it possible to **set** item message headers instead, using the REST API via `ExtendedProperties` ?

This would allow us to remove the last remaining EWS SOAP call we have to do, which is to add a header to an Outlook draft.

The reasons for wanting this:

- Apparently the EWS SOAP API seems to have a failure rate of 10 - 20% of the time, which is a lot:

[image]

these are the response headers from a recent failed SOAP request to set item headers:

`HTTP/2.0 200 OK
cache-control: no-cache, no-store
pragma: no-cache
content-length: 292
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-encoding: gzip
expires: -1
vary: Accept-Encoding
p3p: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
set-cookie: OpenIdConnect.token.v1=AQAAAOADAADFvAnVWFaCHx5XIFrC14By45JdwIaJciEmq6QxjeEkDuu2FkvvzPTFQT48FfepaPUSJwOYaWPsN17BxG86W2EdRhra3LCEm0I7uqQ==; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-OWA-CANARY=rLiI6SI6hEG8TKmFC33h0nDLEd7HytUY6h5Nd5-yklT1lwE6CMOtZ4E6DlBkS8aT6hvMlUUzYRM.; path=/; secure
request-id: c1fcc6a9-e5f7-4376-8601-ed818121c114
x-calculatedbetarget: VI1PR01MB1245.eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com
x-backendhttpstatus: 200
x-rum-validated: 1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-ms-appid: 00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000
x-owa-version: 15.20.820.15
x-owa-owsversion: V2018_01_18
x-owa-minimumsupportedowsversion: V2_6
x-owa-httphandler: true
x-owa-diagnosticsinfo: 83;0;0
x-owa-correlationid: EEA57A52016E48BD82069FA4CF1379A5_152819141147695
x-owa-clientbegin: 2018-06-05T09:36:51.476
x-frontend-begin: 2018-06-05T09:36:51.464
x-backend-begin: 2018-06-05T09:36:51.564
x-backend-end: 2018-06-05T09:36:51.658
x-diaginfo: VI1PR01MB1245
x-beserver: VI1PR01MB1245
x-ua-compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-frontend-end: 2018-06-05T09:36:51.651
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
x-feserver: VI1PR0101CA0061
x-msedge-ref: Ref A: 9251B1F610474C6F83A4DEFEA3C14797 Ref B: AMS04EDGE0917 Ref C: 2018-06-05T09:36:51Z
date: Tue, 05 Jun 2018 09:36:51 GMT
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2`

- Not having to mix and match EWS SOAP API and REST API requests and remove SOAP XML related code.

Related: 
[extendedProperties sample request in REST API sandbox fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433163/extendedproperties-sample-request-in-rest-api-sandbox-fails)   ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -1):

I am curious about the 10-20% failure rate you are seeing with the EWS API.  What failures are you seeing?

As for setting headers, REST actually uses the EWS business logic under the covers, so what worked in EWS should also work in REST (with some exceptions).  For instance, you should be able to follow the below via REST extended props:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn596091(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: I'll keep a watch on whenever one such error presents itself, as it happens non-deterministic, but off the top of my head, the error was something like this:
`statusCode: 0`, `description: the connection was severed serverside`.
regarding EWS / REST, I was already assuming that the REST API was being built on top of existing serverside business logic.
Can you elaborate what you stated about extended properties? I don't follow.

Comment: Sorry, I now understand my question is not entirely clear: I mean to set headers using the JavaScript REST API, not the C# REST API.

Comment: Why can I not @ you, David Sterling? Anyway, I have updated my question with a screenshot of the failing SOAP call.

Comment: @MichaelTrouw - I guess I am unmentionable :)  As for the error, do you  see high latencies on those calls?

Comment: How can I figure that out ? I don't see any failed request in the log in the `Network` tab of google DevTools, also I have no idea what the request actually looks like, because we are using the OfficeJs' `mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync()`

Comment: Regarding latency, you could do it by inspection worst case.  Just make a call and see how much clock time it takes. There are cases where the server will terminate the request, but those should be pretty infrequent (such as http.sys killing the connection due to the min_bytesread protection being violated - basically reading a response too slowly).

Comment: Here are my adhoc manual perf testing results: http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/view/ro.7qKtoqi6JMz/latest

on average, with- and without sucky simulated latency:
`421,220743815104167`, `649,4720703125`, `308,599039713541667` `ms` latencies.
our office is in NL, I'm on cable. When I load OWA, req's have 1-200ms latencies grouped by 1-5 for fast calls and 5-200ms for bigger calls.

Comment: What are these calls doing?  Are these setting the headers, or something else (views, searches, etc..)?

Comment: They are only setting `InternetHeaders`: https://gist.github.com/michahell/a9ec2f4e96e2f89add58cfa1e90d8367
I have only included the code necesary to make the request and excluded handling and parsing. I'm sorry about the indentation, for some reason GH does not set it to 2 when I tell it to.

Comment: still no complete answer

Comment: If you could provide a request id, UTC date time and the X-BEServer from the response headers, I can dig in a bit more into what was happening on the server.  A relatively recent example would be helpful.

Comment: Okay, I will need to start testing sending mails then, I haven't been able to do that as I needed to focus on development.

Comment: I just ran into one such situation - this is the screenshot of the failed request: https://imgur.com/a/ak75u1m. The full response headers are added to the post.

Comment: Were you able to figure out what was the cause ?

Comment: one of our engineers just inspected the HAR files of successful and unsuccessful requests and it seems that failed requests are offered a closed connection, hinting at a connection pooling issue on your side. Could you please look into this.

Comment: Regarding that error, did that come back from the server or was it generated on the client?  If from the server, it will typically have some http response headers which are helpful (requestId, UTC DateTime, X-BEServer)

Comment: It came back from the server :) See the list of `http response headers` in the question itself, `X-BEServer` is also listed: `VI1PR01MB1245`

Comment: Do you have a more recent repro by chance?  We don't store logs for very long and that repro was from June.